# How to use pseudo classes when button clicked show title text

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, mantine

I would like that the user enters their name in input, then when button to save is clicked the button disappears and the user name appears. (Using createstyles I'm aware I could write a function)

I want to use pseudo classes and am currently using mantine as a design framework.
I thought I could nest the title class inside of the button css to that when button is active title is no longer visible.
It seems in mantine that you cannot style two classes at once like in css:

```
.button .title {
}
```

Currently if you hold the mouse down the button stays hidden while click is held but then reappears, I would like it to stay gone. Although this doesn't effect the visibility of the title class.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Container, Title, TextInput, Button, Group, Header, createStyles } from '@mantine/core';
import { useStateWithLocalStorage } from './UseStateWithLocalStorage';
import { WeatherContext } from './WeatherComponent';
import { MdWbSunny } from 'react-icons/md';
import { BsFillCloudSnowFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { IoIosPartlySunny } from 'react-icons/io';

const useStyles = createStyles((theme) => ({
  title: {
    visibility: 'hidden',
  },

      button: {
    color: theme.white,
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.blue[6],
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: theme.radius.md,
    padding: `${theme.spacing.sm}px ${theme.spacing.lg}px`,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    margin: theme.spacing.md,

    
    '&:active': {
      display: 'none',
      title: {
        visibility: 'visible',
      },
    },
  },
}));
 
  

const UserForm = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useStateWithLocalStorage('', 'form');
  const { classes } = useStyles();
  // const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  const weatherIcon = useContext(WeatherContext);
  function handleChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) {
    setInputValue(() => ({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    }));
  }

  return (
    <Header height={56} mb={20}>
      <Container
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: 'gray',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          color: 'white',
          alignItems: 'center',
          padding: '10px',
          fontSize: '25px',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          boxShadow: '0 3px 6px 0 #555',
        }}
      >
        <Group>
          <Title order={2}>Welcome </Title>

          <TextInput
            className="title"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            placeholder="enter your name"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={inputValue.name}
          />

          <Button className={classes.button}>SAVE</Button>

          <Title className={classes.title} order={2}>
            {inputValue.name ? inputValue.name : ''}
          </Title>
        </Group>

        <Group style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
          <Title order={2}>
            {weatherIcon === 'Sunny' ? (
              <MdWbSunny data-testid="sunny" />
            ) : weatherIcon === 'Snowing' ? (
              <BsFillCloudSnowFill data-testid="snowing" />
            ) : (
              <IoIosPartlySunny data-testid="overcast" />
            )}
          </Title>
        </Group>
      </Container>
    </Header>
  );
};
export default UserForm;
```

I guess I would like to know if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getRef` if you want to use css selectors in Mantine.

Check: https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine/discussions/1277

Comment: This actually is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you can use this very simple code instead of your script. It will ask for your name, and when you click the button, show the text, and replace the text with whatever you typed. Next, it will hide the form.

```js
// This is the JavaScript

form = document.getElementById("form");
showUsername = document.getElementById("showUsername");
form.style.display = "block";
showUsername.style.display = "none";
function setUsername() {
    username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    form.style.display = "none";
    showUsername.style.display = "block";
    showUsername.innerHTML = username;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is the HTML: -->
<div id="form">
<input type="text" placeholder="Type your name here..."
 size="50" id="username">
<button onclick="setUsername()">Set Username</button>
 </div>
 <p id="showUsername"></p>
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this I've had functioning code but would like to do it with mantine createStyles.